# Fixing issues in YouTrack from SubVersion commit comments using TeamCity

Tags: teamcity, youtrack

I have a TeamCity server and a YouTrack server working with SubVersion. I have enable integration in the two JB applications.

Is it possible to changes the status of YT issues from comments in the SubVersion commit comments? I.e. TC will update the YT status accordingly, and set in YT which version the fix was done.

Comment: **N.B.** Do not put a period on the end... ie do not do `#BUG-NUM Fixed.` (notice the period on the end). Youtrack's command parser is sort of astonishingly stupid compared to other bugtrackers.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, f.e. you can write

```
#TST-12 Fixed
```

in you commit message which will transit #TST-12 to the Fixed state.
For more details look [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/YTD6/Executing+Commands+from+Comment+to+VCS+Commit).

Comment: I just gave it a try. I get the following message: "YouTrack user could not be found. Reason: No user information provided by TeamCity" under the issue's TeamCity Changes tab.

Comment: Try to synchronize emails of the svn user, TeamCity user and YouTrack user.

Comment: How do I set the email address of a subversion users? I have synchronized the other two.

Comment: Probably it's not necessary. Does TeamCity see your commits? Does YouTrack show your commits in TeamCity changes tab of issue (commit message must contain issue id, f.e. PRJ-123)?

Comment: Yes. In Youtrack I can see "#WS-20 fixed" but "fixed" is underlined red, as is the "user" in TeacmCity changes tab.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: **N.B.** Do not put a period on the end... ie do not do `Fixed.` (notice the period on the end). Youtrack's command parser is sort of stupid compared to other bugtrackers.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to make sure TC is able to match a VCS user to it's user. Check a change in changes log of TeamCity (Build->Changes log). In case you see 'TeamCity user: Unknown (none of TeamCity users defined %user.name% username in his/her VCS username settings)' you should associate a VCS user name with your profile: %your_TC_server_url%/profile.html -> General tab -> Version Control Username Settings.
This will make TC recognize VCS user.

Please also be aware of requirements related to permissions of TeamCity user which integration runs on behalf of. Please find more details here: http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/JT-8233#comment=27-230640

Hope this helps.