# YouTrack, TeamCity, SVN Integration Issue

Tags: svn, teamcity, youtrack

Good morning. I'm having an issue with integrating YouTrack (YT, 5.0.3 (build #7423)), TeamCity (TC, 8.0.4 (build 27616)), SVN, and VS 2012. There are 2 users in TC and YT: root and jmmooney. My email address in both TC and YT is the same for user jmmooney (no email for root user), as well as my SVN account (not that it matters). I am using the Team City plugin for Visual Studio.

**My issue** is that commands are not executed against issues when I commit. The error I receive in YouTrack is:

> "No users info provided by Team City."
>
> [image]

YouTrack User:

> [image]

Team City User:

> [image]

Links that got me here:

-[Executing Commands from Comment to VCS Commit](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/YTD5/Executing+Commands+from+Comment+to+VCS+Commit)

-[Fixing issues in YouTrack from SubVersion commit comments using TeamCity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6977711)

> > The issue I see is that TeamCity is not sending user info to YouTrack and I do not see any setting in which to do so. I thought it would automatically send the user info to YouTrack. Any ideas? I've serached through all questions on StackOverflow that I can find with searching.

Edit (More Details)

> Team City does see my commits, and shows my username as the commiter. YouTrack sees every commit with the issue attached to it. But the same error persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please set SVN username in your TeamCity user profile (http://your.teamcity/vcsSettings.html). This will make TC match your SVN user to TC user.

Comment: Thank you. I have my VCS username set correctly; but it was also set for 2 other users to my username. All is well and commands apply too :). So happy.